# Avoid instanceof but restrict function parameter to a set of subclasses of a superclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

In other words how to force a method to only use subclasses of the given input parameter which is a superclass?

Example:

```
public class Animal {
    ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
...
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
...
}

public class Test {
   ...
   public void makeSound(Animal animal) throws Exception{
      if(animal instanceof Dog){
         System.out.println("bark");
      } else if (animal instanceof Cat) {
        System.out.println("meow");
      } else {
        throw new Exception ("Not valid subclass of Animal");
      }
   }
}
```

The code above seems somehow wrong, is there a better, more efficient or generic way?

Comment: What is your expected output? How is that code wrong. Your question is not very clear for now. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I want to have the makeSound() function in the example above only process Dogs or Cats, and any other future subtypes of Animal. In the example, every time you add another subtype of Animal, you have to go in and modify the makeSound() function. Is there any way to make the code more polymorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid doing the `instanceof` check for each subtype, you can create an abstract `makeSound()` method in `Animal` class, and override in all the subclasses. I would make the `Animal` class `abstract`, as it really is an abstract entity in your scenario:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract void makeSound();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    void makeSound() { System.out.println("Bark"); }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    void makeSound() { System.out.println("Meow"); }
}
```

and then in `Test` class, just invoke `makeSound` on `Animal` reference. It will call appropriate overridden method based on actual instance:

```
public void makeSound(Animal animal){
    animal.makeSound();
}
```

Now, everytime you add a new subtype of `Animal`, you just need to override `makeSound()` in that class. With abstract method, you will be forced to do that. And keep the `Test#makeSound()` method unmodified.